# Как можно скачать php файлы?

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста, можно как то скачать php файлы если я вижу их в таком виде? Сайт сделан на wordpress!
[image]

Comment: с помощью скриптов можно, даже тем же php https://stackoverflow.com/a/41559101/6104996   и https://stackoverflow.com/a/6321323/6104996

Comment: Правой кнопкой мышки по файлу, и "Сохранить ссылку как..."

Comment: Так скачиваеться пустой файл